# How do I make a YouTube video seek when it first loads?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've been using the YouTube API, and one task I have is that when a YouTube video loads, I might want it to immediately move to a particular point in the video - for instance - point 5 minutes and 10 seconds.  In other words, I don't want it to play the first 5 minutes and 10 seconds, I want I to skip that section.

I find that this does not work with any browser.

I tried it in the 'onPlayerReady" event, and it failed.

So I tried it when YT.PlayerState.Cued is fired, and that failed too.

Has anyone ever gotten this to work?  It sounds pretty basic.

One caution: I don't use iframes directly, instead I create the iframe in code. (using code such as  player = new YT.Player('player', {).  The seek is done with a call such as "player.seekTo(sp, true);"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [loadVideoById](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=fr#loadVideoById)

```
player.loadVideoById(videoId:String, startSeconds:Number, suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

For exemple :

```
player.loadVideoById('videoid', 500);
```

And your video will start at the 500 seconds

If you post your code, we can help you more more than a simple link to the doc.

**EDIT**

Exemple of `new YT.Player` with no video-id, the player is just loaded not the video.

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: '636',
    height: '360',
    playerVars: {
    'controls' : 0,
    'showinfo' : 0,
    'modestbranding' : 0,
    'rel' : 0
  },
  events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
    'onError': onPlayerError
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this line reload the entire video?  (I ask this because the video does load when you create it with New YT.player... and it does obey API commands in general.)

Comment: @user3903798 Nop, because i don't passe any youtube Id on the `YT.Player` function. The function just prepare the player with no video. After the player is ready, i use `player.loadVideoById('videoid', 500);` -> load the video, and after `player.play();`. Like i say, it's difficult to show you something you want to do in your code if you don't post the code :) I made an edit of my previous answer.